# Two methods of swapping integers using pointers, which is better?[C]

Tags: c, pointers, swap

i have encountered two methods of swapping two integer values and I’m confused about the difference.

Method1(temp is a pointer):

```
 void Swap(int *a, int *b)
 {
  int *temp = a; 
  *a = *b;
  *b = *temp;
  }
```

Method2(temp is not a pointer):

```
  void Swap(int *a, int *b)
  {
  int temp = *a; 
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
   }
```

I don’t understand the difference between two methods, and is one method better than the other?

Comment: Did you at least test them both and compare the result?

Comment: *i have encountered two methods* I hope not.  The first method is completely, almost laughably wrong.  The second is the only conceivably correct way to do it.  If you're swapping integer values, you obviously need an integer temporary.  If there are pointers involved, they're only to pass the initial values in and the modified values out; you would never have any reason to use a pointer as your temporary.

Comment: @Bar I would say that the first method is more interesting.:) There is something you should think about.:) The second method is too trivially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's easier to understand the first (wrong) function if we draw it out?

When the function is called, it will be something like this:

```
+---+      +-------------+
| a | ---> | value for a |
+---+      +-------------+

+---+      +-------------+
| b | ---> | value for b |
+---+      +-------------+
```

Then after the initialization of `temp` you will have this:

```
+---+            +-------------+
| a | -----+---> | value for a |
+---+      |     +-------------+
           |
+------+   |
| temp | --/
+------+

+---+      +-------------+
| b | ---> | value for b |
+---+      +-------------+
```

You have two pointers, pointing to the same location.

Then you do the assignment

```
*a = *b;
```

which leads to this situation:

```
+---+            +-------------+
| a | -----+---> | value for b |
+---+      |     +-------------+
           |
+------+   |
| temp | --/
+------+

+---+      +-------------+
| b | ---> | value for b |
+---+      +-------------+
```

As can easily be seen, the `value for a` is lost.

---

PS.

Whenever you have troubles with pointers, and can't really visualize what's happening, I recommend you take a step back, fetch a pencil and paper, and draw it all out.

Comment: Thank you, the visualisation was very helpful.

Comment: @Bar I still use the same visualization technique after 40 years when it looks hard.  Pen and paper rocks when it comes to dealing with stuff like this.

Answer (score 4):

The first method does not work, because the former contents of the `int` pointed to by `a` is not saved. The initialization`temp = a` copies only the *pointer*.

You might want to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to see what happens.

Comment: So in the next line:
*b = *temp;     
*b receives a garbage value?

Comment: No, it will receive the value pointed to by `a` (and `temp`) which is actually now the value of `*b` itself (because of `*a = *b;` in the previous line). So `*b` will not change.

Answer (score 1):

what happens in the first method is that temp points to the same address as a;
upon changing *a to what b points to, temp now points to what b (and a) now point to.

after the statement *b=*temp, you changed nothing, as if you have said *b=*b;

Answer (score 0):

In this function

```
 void Swap(int *a, int *b)
 {
  int *temp = a; 
  *a = *b;
  *b = *temp;
  }
```

after this record

```
  int *temp = a;
```

the both pointers `a` and `temp` point to the same object that was changed by the value stored in the object pointed to by the pointer `b`.

```
  *a = *b;
```

So as a result the value stored in the object pointed by the pointer `a` was lost.

It seems that when you copied the function you was not attentive and made a typo. The function will make a sense if to make the following changes

```
 void Swap(int **a, int **b)
 {
  int *temp = *a; 
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
  }
```

Such a function is designed to swap two pointers of the type `int *`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Swap(int *a, int *b)
{
     int *temp = a; 
     *a = *b;       
     *b = *temp;   
}
```

'a' and 'b' in memory look like this:

`a    --> address of an integer`

`b    --> address of an integer`

In the first function you create
`int *temp = a`

which looks like this in memory

`temp --> a`

`temp` will store the address of the integer that 'a' points too.

then you do

`*a = *b`

a and b currently look like this:

`a    --> address of an integer`

`b    --> address of an integer`

the operation will get the integer value from "address of an integer" for 'b' and store it in "address of an integer" for 'a'

*** Now 'a' and 'b' store the same integer value ***

At this stage you should remember that `temp` also points to 'a' (and we have just edited 'a').

Lastly you do

`*b = *temp`

which will basically do nothing since

1. `temp --> a` (temp points to a)
2. 'a' and 'b' have the same integer value
3. so doing `*b = *temp` just assigns *b with the value it already has.

So in the end this function has just assigned 'a' and 'b' with the same value

```
void Swap(int *a, int *b)
{
     int temp = *a; 
     *a = *b;
     *b = temp;
}
```

This function will work unlike the previous one because it will store the integer value of 'a' into `temp`, then it will edit *a, then edit b with the previously saved value of `temp`.